# Binding to a member function which takes no parameters?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

In WPF VS2010, is it possible to bind to a member function which takes no parameters?

In particular I'd like to call my object's .ToString() method.

I don't see why it's not possible, but I can't get it to work. 
It seems silly and pollutes my code to add a property that simply calls ToString.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="myKey" d:IsDataSource="True" ObjectType="{x:Type MyNameSpace:MyClass}" MethodName="ToString"/>
```

and

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myKey}}" />
```